# How i get a best mysql grouping result with join product and city tables?

Tags: mysql, case, grouping

I have a few tables joined to make a query, City, Product, Marca, and Sales, I need grouping by product and show de average by sales in each city

```
SELECT m.marca, p.producto,
case when ci.id_ciudad = 1 then AVG(a.valor) end as medellin,
case when ci.id_ciudad = 126 then AVG(a.valor) end as barranquilla,
case when ci.id_ciudad = 149 then AVG(a.valor) end as bogota,
case when ci.id_ciudad = 150 then AVG(a.valor) end as cartagena,
case when ci.id_ciudad = 1004 then AVG(a.valor) end as cali
FROM tbma_productos p 
LEFT JOIN tbma_activacion_producto a  on p.id_producto = a.id_producto
LEFT JOIN tbma_activaciones i on i.id_instalacion = a.id_activacion
LEFT JOIN tbax_almacenes c on c.id_almacen = i.id_punto_venta
LEFT JOIN tbax_ciudades ci on ci.id_ciudad = c.id_ciudad
LEFT JOIN tbax_marcas m on m.id_marca = p.id_marca
where a.id_producto BETWEEN 71 and 88 and i.id_estado_instalacion in (19,20)
GROUP by ci.id_ciudad, p.id_producto
ORDER by ci.id_ciudad,m.id_marca, p.id_producto
```

and this is the result
[image]

**but I need something like that:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the city from the group by clause. Accordingly, the conditional expression need to go within the aggregate functions:

```
SELECT p.producto,
    AVG(case when ci.id_ciudad =   1 then a.valor end) as medellin,
    AVG(case when ci.id_ciudad = 126 then a.valor end as barranquilla,
    ...
FROM tbma_productos                p 
LEFT JOIN tbma_activacion_producto a  on p.id_producto = a.id_producto
LEFT JOIN tbma_activaciones        i  on i.id_instalacion = a.id_activacion
LEFT JOIN tbax_almacenes           c  on c.id_almacen = i.id_punto_venta
LEFT JOIN tbax_ciudades            ci on ci.id_ciudad = c.id_ciudad
LEFT JOIN tbax_marcas              m  on m.id_marca = p.id_marca
where a.id_producto BETWEEN 71 and 88 and i.id_estado_instalacion in (19,20)
GROUP BY p.id_producto 
ORDER BY p.id_producto
```

I don't know if you want `m.marca` in the `group by` clause or not. It is not showing in your desired results, so I removed it.